# Missing one post when fetching using Rest Api

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i am making app with Xcode using Rest Api and fetching data from my WordPress Website , all works fine but the problem is that my website has 15 posts but in app i can see only 14 posts and the very last post is missing , please help

this is my code

```
 let url = URL(string: "https://www.pbkalam.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?page=\(page)\(sortBy)" )!
        print(url)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let data = data else {return}
            
            do {
                let postsData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data)
                completionHandler(postsData)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    
                    }
            }
            catch {
                let error = error
                print(String(describing: error))
                
             }
         }
      task.resume()
```

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.item == self.newsData.count - 1 {  //numberofitem count
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
                self.page += 1
                self.updateNextSet()
                SVProgressHUD.show()
            }
        }
    }
```

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "postcell", for: indexPath) as! ViewCell
            cell.setup(with: newsData[indexPath.row-(indexPath.row/4)])
            cell.backgroundColor = .white
            return cell
```

i have tried this but not works

```
if indexPath.item == self.newsData.count {  //numberofitem count
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
                self.page += 1
                self.updateNextSet()
```

Comment: How do you set 'page'? And what does the json response look like?

Comment: For me your link returns 10 for page 1 and 5 for page 2. Please clarify what your problem is. Fetching the data or presenting it.

Comment: @burnsi my problem is presenting data in app, i can see 5 posts on page 2 in browser as well but in app when i present data using collectionView it only shows 14 posts instead of 15